# Where is the early warning on the LTO tape?

Tags: scsi, lto

SSC5 says:

> 4.2.5 Early-warning If writing, the application client needs an indication that it is approaching the end of the permissible recording
>   area (i.e., end of the partition (see 4.2.7)). This position, called
>   early-warning (EW), is typically reported to the application client at
>   a position early enough for the device to write any buffered logical
>   objects to the medium while still leaving enough room for additional
>   recorded logical objects (see figure 10 and figure 11). Some American National Standards include physical requirements for a marker placed on the medium to be detected by the device
>   as early-warning.

Can anyone tell me where EW is on the LTO tape, e.g LTO-5 or LTO-6?
Whether it depends on the vendor of the tape?
Whether they are tens or hundreds of MB's from EW to EOP?
I can't find the reference...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct quote from [HPE LTO-6 White Paper](http://www.hpestoragesupplies.com/html_emails/InterleaveTesting/InterleaveTesting-WhitePaper-EMEA_eee.pdf). Note: EWEOM stands for "Early Warning End Of Media".

> The EWEOM is set to be slightly less than the native capacity of 2.5 TB for LTO-6 cartridges, as required by the LTO format.

> Crucially, however, the EWEOM is slightly before the actual physical end of tape which means every LTO Ultrium format cartridge has a little bit more capacity than the stated headline figure. For LTO-6, this additional space is the equivalent of an additional 5% of capacity, although it is reserved exclusively for the system and cannot be accessed
> via the backup software. The excess tape is the first section of the media that is used when there are higher than expected errors so that any rewrite and error correction takes place without losing the stated capacity of the tape.

Going back to your questions:

*Can anyone tell me where EW is on the LTO tape, e.g LTO-5 or LTO-6?*

- 5% of additional capacity corresponds to 125GB in LTO-6 media (2500GB * 5% = 125GB). This number means that the position of EW (EWEOM) in LTO-6 should be located at roughly 7 wraps before EOP. Note: 1wrap = 18GB in LTO-6. Please note that this location depends on generations. As an example, if we assume that LTO-5 media also has 5% of additional capacity, there should be 75GB for this region, and this capacity corresponds to roughly 4 wraps. This is just an example - I could not find the exact spare capacity of LTO-5.

*Whether it depends on the vendor of the tape?*

- Since this spare capacity is required by LTO format, I believe that the location is independent on tape manufacturers.

*Whether they are tens or hundreds of MB's from EW to EOP?*

- Once again, LTO-6 has 5% of spare capacity which corresponds to 125GB. I guess that this margin depends on generations, but it should be roughly a few percentages. This is my best guess.